# C++ - Assigning character values to a string in a vector using range based for loop doesn't assign the value

Tags: c++, stdstring

I'm working on a self-imposed practice exercise. The parameters are that I allow the user to enter a name that is stored in a vector. Printing the list of names in the vector gives you the position of each name. You can choose to encrypt a name in the list by providing the name's position. Encryption compares each letter in the name with another string that is the allowed alphabet for names. When it finds the letter in the alphabet, it pulls a corresponding character from another string of random characters and assigns the new character to the same position.

Using a range based for loop I almost got it to work. By adding output statements I can see the code correctly comparing the characters of a name to the allowed alphabet and finding the corresponding value in the encryption key. However when the loop is complete and I print the list of names again, the characters in the name to be encrypted are unchanged.

Trying to troubleshoot the issue, I have commented out the range based for loop and tried to do the same thing with a traditional for loop. With this code I get and error during encryption:

> Position 1 A is the same as @
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>     what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 26) >= this->size() (which is 2)

The **"Position 1 A is the same as @"** line is a debug output that I added to show that the code is able to find the correct string, a letter in the string, and the corresponding letter in they key.

Any help in understanding why I get those errors would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declare strings for Encryption and Decryption
    string alphabet {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "};
    string key {"mnbvfghytcqwi1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]\{}|;':,./<>?"};

    //Declare collection of names for the list
    vector <string> names {};

    //Declare character to hold the user menu selection
    char selection {};
    string user_input{};
    string banner (50, '=');
    //Print menu
    do
    {
        cout << "\n" << banner << endl;
        cout << "A - Add name to list" << endl;
        cout << "P - Print all names in list" << endl;
        cout << "E - Encrypt a name in the list" << endl;
        cout << "D - Decrypt a name in the list" << endl;
        cout << "S - Show details of a name in the list" << endl;
        cout << "C - Clear all names in the list" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;
        cout << banner << endl;
        cout << "Selection: ";
        getline(cin, user_input);
        if (user_input.size() != 1)
        {
            cout << "Error 4: Menu selection must be a single character" << endl;
            selection = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto c: user_input)
            {
                if (!isalpha(c))
                {
                    cout << "Error 5: Menu selection must be an alphabetic character" << endl;
                    selection = '1';
                }
                else
                    selection = c;

            }
        }
        // cin >> selection;
        // cin.clear();
        // cin.sync();

        switch (selection)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
            {
               string temp_name{};
               bool invalid_name {false};
               cout << "Enter full name: ";
               getline(cin, temp_name);
               if (!isalpha(temp_name[0]))
                   cout << "Error 2: Names must begin with an alphabetic character" << endl << endl;
                else 
                {
                    for (auto c: temp_name)
                    {
                        if (!isalpha(c) && !isspace(c) && c != '-')
                        {
                            invalid_name = true;
                            break;
                        }   
                        else
                            invalid_name = false;
                    }
                    if (invalid_name)
                        cout << "Error 3: Name contains invalid characters" << endl << endl;
                    else
                    {
                        temp_name.at(0) = toupper (temp_name.at(0));
                        for (size_t i {1}; i < temp_name.size(); i++)
                        {
                            size_t position{i-1};
                            if (isspace(temp_name.at(position)) || temp_name.at(position) == '-')
                            {
                                temp_name.at(i) = toupper(temp_name.at(i));
                            }
                        }
                        names.push_back(temp_name);
                        cout << "Added name #" << names.size() << endl;
                    }
                }
               break;
            }
            case 'p':
            case 'P':
            {
                for (size_t i {0}; i < names.size(); i++)
                    cout << i+1 << ". " << names.at(i) << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            {
                size_t encrypt_input{}, key_position{}, name_position {}, name_size {};
                cout << "Enter the position of the name to encrypt: ";
                cin >> encrypt_input;
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                if (encrypt_input < 1 || encrypt_input > names.size())
                    cout << "Error 6: Invalid selection for name to encrypt" << endl << endl;
                else
                {
                    name_position = encrypt_input - 1;
                    name_size = names.at(name_position).size();
                    cout << "Encrypting name: " << names.at(name_position) << " of size " << name_size << endl << endl;
                    cout << "Position 1 " << names.at(name_position).at(0) << " is the same as ";
                    key_position = alphabet.find(names.at(name_position).at(0));
                    cout << key.at(key_position) << endl;
                    for (size_t i {0}; i < name_size; i++)
                    {
                        key_position = alphabet.find(names.at(name_position).at(i));
                        cout << "Finding " << names.at(key_position).at(i) << " in key at position " << key_position << endl;
                        cout << "Found encryption value of " << key.at(key_position) << " at position " << key_position << endl;
                        cout << "Changing " << names.at(key_position).at(i) << " to " << key.at(key_position) << endl;
                        names.at(name_position).at(i) = key.at(key_position);
                    }
                    /*
                    for (auto c: names.at(encrypt_input-1))
                    {
                        cout << "Converting " << c << " to ";
                        key_position = alphabet.find(c);
                        cout << key.at(key_position) << endl;
                        c = key.at(key_position);
                        cout << "C is now " << c << endl << endl;
                    } 
                     */
                }
                cout << names.at(encrypt_input-1) << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                cout << "Goodbye" << endl << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error 1: Invalid menu selection" << endl << endl;
                break;
        }
    } while (selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should learn to write functions that do one thing ( a function to encrypt a string, a function to decrypt a string, etc.) instead of sticking everything into one gigantic `main` function.  Then you could test each function to see if they work properly.  Right now, you have one big pile of code and not know where or how you got an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Your problem seem to be in the `find`, you still write your `find` without checking whether it is really a number or `npos`, `npos` means C++ stdlib didn't find your substring in the string.  So, check it before trying to make `at(key_position)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!  I agree entirely with PaulMcKenzie that such a big function is not the best for a variety of reasons - the immediate reasons are that its hard to read and hard to find problems - but there are more reasons as well.

Having said that you have a bug that I can see in the `E` case.

```
                for (size_t i {0}; i < name_size; i++)
                {
                    key_position = alphabet.find(names.at(name_position).at(i));
                    cout << "Finding " << names.at(key_position).at(i) << " in key at position " << key_position << endl;
                    cout << "Found encryption value of " << key.at(key_position) << " at position " << key_position << endl;
                    cout << "Changing " << names.at(key_position).at(i) << " to " << key.at(key_position) << endl;
                    names.at(name_position).at(i) = key.at(key_position);
                }
```

Should be

```
        for (unsigned int i{ 0 }; i < name_size; i++)
        {
            key_position = alphabet.find(names.at(name_position).at(i));
            cout << "Finding " << names.at(name_position).at(i) << " in key at position " << key_position << endl;
            cout << "Found encryption value of " << key.at(key_position) << " at position " << key_position << endl;
            cout << "Changing " << names.at(name_position).at(i) << " to " << key.at(key_position) << endl;
            names.at(name_position).at(i) = key.at(key_position);
        }
```

ie `key_position` should be `name_position` in 2 places.

There may be other bugs, but this should stop the crashing and do the encoding right.

EDIT: On request of OP have added a new code fragment.

```
int i = 0;  // position counter
for (auto c: names.at(encrypt_input-1))
{
    cout << "Converting " << c << " to ";
    key_position = alphabet.find(c);
    cout << key.at(key_position) << endl;
    c = key.at(key_position);
    cout << "C is now " << c << endl << endl;
    names.at(name_position).at(i++) = c;  // update the names variable.
}
```

This should solve the problem you mentioned for the auto loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. I completely agree with breaking the program apart into functions. Unfortunately I am not up to that lesson yet. I am doing a course on Udemy and am working my way through c++ style strings. The instructor gave a challenge for a simple program to do the encryption of a name. I made it more complicated (bigger) so that I could practice and reinforce my use of vectors and looping.

Comment: I have made the changes and it worked. I do have a question on another piece of that code, though. I tried the same thing with a range based for loop (commented out above). No errors, and the output statements show that it found the correct values, but when I printed the list again the name was unchanged. Any ideas

    for (auto c: names.at(encrypt_input-1))
    {
        cout << "Converting " << c << " to ";
        key_position = alphabet.find(c);
        cout << key.at(key_position) << endl;
        c = key.at(key_position);
        cout << "C is now " << c << endl << endl;
    }

Comment: Ok I can see that you are not updating the names variable in the second loop. I have updated the post to show what I mean.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, you are free to upvote using the using the up/down arrows at top left of my reply, and accept the answer using the tick under the up/down arrow. This is optional but is helpful for everyone, and closes off the questions for statistical purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up! I took some c++ classes decades ago, and I guess in my head I thought that the 'c' in the for loop acted as a pointer back to the original. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing an invalid location of `names` vector and the error / exception is showing that.

When you do this:

```
names.at( key_position ).at( i )
//        ^^^
//        It should be name_position
```

in this statement,

```
cout << "Finding " << names.at( key_position ).at( i ) << " in key at position " << key_position << endl;
```

you're accessing an invalid index of `names` whereas it should be:

```
names.at( name_position ).at( i )
```

and, that'll work because it access a valid index.

You're making the same mistake in this statement as well:

```
cout << "Changing " << names.at( key_position ).at( i ) << " to " << key.at( key_position ) << endl;
```

Correct these and it should work!

---

**Tip:**

It's time you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).
It'll help you figure out what's wrong with your program in a more systematic way.

---

A few points regarding your code organization in general:

- You should divide your program in functions instead of cluttering the `main` function.
- You may write functions corresponding to each of your `case` in `switch` statement e.g. `addName()`, `encryptName()`, `decryptName()`, etc.
- This modularity will definitely help you and other people to read, debug, maintain and extend your code easily and efficiently. In your case, it would also help you write an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in no time.

---

Hope that helps!
Best of luck!
Happy coding!

Comment: I see what you mean. I think that the upcoming modules in the lesson I'm following deal with functions and objects, so I'll be able to better break up the program. Thanks for the links as well. They were good reading, and I can see how I didn't step through the program correctly when I was trying to troubleshoot before posting.